# Prove that $\lim_{n->\infty }$ $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof and point mistake

Because

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$

$$ \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right )^{2}< \epsilon^{2} $$

And $$  \frac{1}{\epsilon ^{2}}< n$$ ^ $$\frac{1}{n}< \epsilon^{2} $$

We canconclude

$$    \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \epsilon $$

by transivity

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \epsilon $$

or

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}}< \epsilon $$

Then limit equal 0

Comment: If you're asking that your answer is fine, then it is completely fine.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to write "I want someone to check my proof" -*-

Comment: Write that, because the down vote I guess has come for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

take $N=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\rfloor +1$.

then

$$(\forall n\geq N) \; \;\sqrt{n}>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies$$

$$(\forall n\geq N)\;\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon.$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+7}}=0.$$